# Complete overwrite of current version of android app with update

Tags: android

I am just wondering is there a way to set it up through the manifest or somewhere else that when the user updates your app that it completely overwrites the current version on the device?  I know the default is when the user updates the data etc from the old version is kept.

I am looking to set it up in such a way that there is a completely clean install each time the user updates the app from the play store.

So if anyone has any thoughts or knows how to do this, I'd appreciate hearing them or hearing how.

Gary

Answer (score 1):

Google Play manages the version numbers from your manifest.  So your update for the APP will be complete when your version number changes. If you want to blow away your data after an update, I would suggest that you keep the version number as part of your saved data.  Then, when it updates, it can see that the version number is different and needs to reset the data.

Comment: thank you for your reply...well for example, I am working on a complete overhaul of an app currently on the store, so when we have this new very different version we want to keep our users but completely overwrite the old version/style of the app...

Comment: Well, like I said, the entire app WILL be overwritten.  If your data model has changed, your data will be updated to reflect new stuff.  But any existing values will persist.  So you must have some way to check when the app launches to see if it's the old data model - if it is, reset it and rewrite the date with the new defaults.  Either that, or write a completely NEW data model, and the old one can be ignored.  Sloppy, but functional.

Comment: thanks for your help...it's not ideal really, I had hope that there was a more simple approach like over ride the play store smart update or something along those lines...thank you.

Comment: Look at it this way...  It would probably be dangerous to trust a 3rd party - even Google Play - to know if it has the correct data to use.  You really are better off handling it yourself within the app.